# Is there any way to bound the region searched by NLsolve in Julia?

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization, equation-solving

I'm trying to find one of the roots of a nonlinear (roughly quartic) equation.
The equation always has four roots, a pair of them close to zero, a large positive, and a large negative root. I'd like to identify either of the near zero roots, but `nlsolve`, even with an initial guess very close to these roots, seems to always converge on the large positive or negative root.

A plot of the function essentially looks like a constant negative value, with a (very narrow) even-ordered pole near zero, and gradually rising to cross zero at the large positive and negative roots.

Is there any way I can limit the region searched by `nlsolve`, or do something to make it more sensitive to the presence of this pole in my function?

EDIT:
Here's some example code reproducing the problem:

```
using NLsolve

function f!(F,x)
    x = x[1]
    F[1] = -15000 + x^4 / (x+1e-5)^2
end
# nlsolve will find the root at -122
nlsolve(f!,[0.0])
```

As output, I get:

```
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [0.0]
 * Zero: [-122.47447713915808]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 15
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
   * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 16
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 6
```

We can find the exact roots in this case by transforming the objective function into a polynomial:

```
using PolynomialRoots
roots([-1.5e-6,-0.3,-15000,0,1])
```

produces

```
4-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
     122.47449713915809 - 0.0im
    -122.47447713915808 + 0.0im
 -1.0000000813048448e-5 + 0.0im
  -9.999999186951818e-6 + 0.0im
```

I would love a way to identify the pair of roots around the pole at x = -1e-5 without knowing the exact form of the objective function.

EDIT2:
Trying out `Roots.jl` :

```
using Roots
f(x) = -15000 + x^4 / (x+1e-5)^2

find_zero(f,0.0) # finds +122... root
find_zero(f,(-1e-4,0.0)) # error, not a bracketing interval
find_zeros(f,-1e-4,0.0) # finds 0-element Array{Float64,1}
find_zeros(f,-1e-4,0.0,no_pts=6) # finds root slightly less than -1e-5
find_zeros(f,-1e-4,0.0,no_pts=10) # finds 0-element Array{Float64,1}, sensitive to value of no_pts
```

I can get `find_zeros` to work, but it's very sensitive to the `no_pts` argument and the exact values of the endpoints I pick. Doing a loop over `no_pts` and taking the first non-empty result might work, but something more deterministic to converge would be preferable.

EDIT3 :
Here's applying the tanh transformation suggested by Bogumił

```
using NLsolve
function f_tanh!(F,x)
    x = x[1]
    x = -1e-4 * (tanh(x)+1) / 2
    F[1] = -15000 + x^4 / (x+1e-5)^2
end

nlsolve(f_tanh!,[100.0]) # doesn't converge
nlsolve(f_tanh!,[1e5]) # doesn't converge

using Roots
function f_tanh(x)
    x = -1e-4 * (tanh(x)+1) / 2
    return -15000 + x^4 / (x+1e-5)^2
end

find_zeros(f_tanh,-1e10,1e10) # 0-element Array
find_zeros(f_tanh,-1e3,1e3,no_pts=100) # 0-element Array
find_zero(f_tanh,0.0) # convergence failed
find_zero(f_tanh,0.0,max_evals=1_000_000,maxfnevals=1_000_000) # convergence failed
```

EDIT4 : This combination of techniques identifies at least one root somewhere around 95% of the time, which is good enough for me.

```
using Peaks
using Primes
using Roots

# randomize pole location
a = 1e-4*rand()
f(x) = -15000 + x^4 / (x+a)^2

# do an initial sample to find the pole location
l = 1000
minval = -1e-4
maxval = 0
m = []
sample_r = []
while l < 1e6
    sample_r = range(minval,maxval,length=l)
    rough_sample = f.(sample_r)
    m = maxima(rough_sample)
    if length(m) > 0
        break
    else
        l *= 10
    end
end
guess = sample_r[m[1]]

# functions to compress the range around the estimated pole
cube(x) = (x-guess)^3 + guess 
uncube(x) = cbrt(x-guess) + guess
f_cube(x) = f(cube(x))

shift = l ÷ 1000
low = sample_r[m[1]-shift]
high = sample_r[m[1]+shift]
# search only over prime no_pts, so no samplings divide into each other
# possibly not necessary?
for i in primes(500)
    z = find_zeros(f_cube,uncube(low),uncube(high),no_pts=i)
    if length(z)>0
        println(i)
        println(cube.(z))
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More comment could be given if you provided more information on your problem.

However in general:

1. It seems that your problem is univariate, in which case you can use Roots.jl where `find_zero` and `find_zeros` give the interface you ask for (i.e. allowing to specify the search region)
2. If a problem is multivariate you have several options how to do it in the problem specification for `nlsolve` (as it by default does not allow to specify a bounding box AFAICT). The simplest is to use variable transformation. E.g. you can apply a `ai * tanh(xi) + bi` transformation selecting `ai` and `bi` for each variable so that it is bounded to the desired interval

The first problem you have in your definition is that the way you define `f` it never crosses `0` near the two roots you are looking for because `Float64` does not have enough precision when you write `1e-5`. You need to use greater precision of computations:

```
julia> using Roots

julia> f(x) = -15000 + x^4 / (x+1/big(10.0^5))^2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> find_zeros(f,big(-2*10^-5), big(-8*10^-6), no_pts=100)
2-element Array{BigFloat,1}:
 -1.000000081649671426108658262468117284940444265467160592853348997523986352593615e-05
 -9.999999183503552405580084054429938261707450678661727461293670518591720605751116e-06
```

and set `no_pts` to be sufficiently large to find intervals bracketing the roots.

Comment: Hi Bogumił, thanks for the answer. I tried out some of your suggestions on an example problem, see my edits. `find_zeros` seems to occasionally work, depending on the exact number of subintervals.

Comment: I have commented on what I think was the root cause of your problems.

Comment: Ah, I see, using BigFloats does seem to help. The only issue I have now is that `find_roots` is sensitive to the exact ranges and value of `no_pts`. I'm trying `no_pts=i` in a loop `for i in primes(200)`. This seems to work for some value of `i` about 3/4 of the time. Any ideas how I could speed that up, or avoid doing the loop?

Comment: I do not think it can be easily helped. `find_roots` needs to find two points - one where the function has a positive value and the other where it has a negative value, and then searches this interval, so your search must be dense enough to hit the point between the two zeros, which are very close in your case.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I'll accept your answer. I was able to speed up the search a little bit. I sample the function over a range, then use `Peaks.jl` to identify the approximate location of the pole. Then I reduce the search range to just be around this peak, and do a cubic transformation (so the near-pole region is sampled more densely), then do `find_roots` (still in a loop over `no_pts`, unfortunately). The cubing has the benefit of working decently well with `Float64`s as well. This still fails to identify the roots ~ 5% of the time, but that's good enough for me.